# Как правильно создать тест с помощью xUnit и что тестировать?

Tags: c#, 1с, тестирование, xunit

Всем доброе время суток! Я новичок!!!Только немного разобрался с базой C#. Поэтому даётся не легко.Заранее извиняюсь,если это глупые вопросы!

Есть написанный код на С# с типами данных из 1С, а именно:  `Структура(Ключ,Значение)`
- Она выполнена как аналог `IDictionary (TKey, TValue)` с теми же методами( `Add,Clear` и тд..)

Моя задача заключается в тестировании этих типов данных с помощью **xUnit**.Не совсем понятно как составить в плане синтаксиса сам тест,так как по **xUnit** мало документации.

Вот что надо сделать, как я понимаю:

1. Добавление и удаление записей с помощью методов и проверка на валидность ключей. `Вставить` и `.Удалить`.Это те же `.Add` и `.Remove`. Реализовал так,но не уверен в правильности и подскажите что ещё можно проверить? :

   ```
   [Fact]       
   public void Структура_ДобавлениеУдаление_ВалидностьКлючей()
   {
           Структура СтруктураТест = new Структура();
           СтруктураТест.Вставить("белый", 10); 
           Assert.Equal("белый","белый");
           СтруктураТест.Удалить("белый");
           Assert.Equal("белый", "белый");
   }
   ```
2. Надо перебрать Значения в цикле `foreach`, вызывать все возможные исключения в `try` и `catch` и протестить. Тут я вообще впал в ступор!
   Надо вообще порознь делать цикл и исключения? Или же пихать в цикл блок `try` и `catch`? Пытался реализовать так:

   ```
   [Fact]
   public void Структура_Исключение_Тест() 
   {
       Структура StructSin = new Структура("Белый",25.55);

       foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> ab in StructSin)
       {
           try
           {
               StructSin.Количество();
           }

           catch (Exception )
           {
               Assert.Equal("Key = {1},Value{1}", "Key = {1},Value{1}");

           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Необходимо проверить правильно работы с индексами массива. Оператор `[]`. Без понятия как вообще.

Так же подскажите, что ещё можно протестить или этого достаточно?

Answer (score 2):

1) Один тест -одно утверждение. Никаких ДобавлениеУдаление. Если нужно проверить, что корректно вставляется. Создаешь новое хранилище, вставляешь данные, вроверяешь что данные вставились успешено.

```
Структура СтруктураТест = new Структура();
СтруктураТест.Вставить("белый", 10); 
Assert.Equal(СтруктураТест.Найти("белый"));
```

Т.е. тут можешь исходить из того, что хранилище изначально было пустое. После такого как добавил эелемент -ищем его. Если нашли -значит все ок, функционал на добавление работает. Можешь искать, можешь проверять на существование, на IndexOf(), да даже банально `СтруктураТест["белый"] == 10`

2) В тестах никаких трай-кэтчей, это все должно быть в вызываемом коде, а вот в тестах ты это как раз и проверяешь. Один тест на то, что есть исключение при обращении к пустом хранилищу, один тест на исключение если ключ не существует, один тест если вышел за границы индексов и т.д.

```
    public Item Exist(string key)
    {
        if (_collection.IndexOf(key) < 0)
            throw new ItemNotFoundException();
        return _collection[key];
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Try_Get_Exist_Item()
    {
        var collection = new MySuperStruct();
        Assert.Throws<ItemNotFoundException>(() => collection.collection.Exist("blablabla"););
    }
```

3) Ну тут сложно что-то сказать, зависит от того как у вас реализован индексатор, для доступа к хранилищу. Если поддерживает обращение по ключам, `Item this[key string]` проверь что получешь нужный объект, что есть исключение если ключ -пустая строка. `Item this[int index]` если по индексу -то как минимум, что не выходишь за границы.

Comment: Ну можете не искать, если нет реализации поиска. В пустую коллекцию добавьте елемент, а в ассёрте проверьте, что елементов в коллекции ровно 1. Ассерт.Тру(коллекция.каунт == 0), как-то так. Позже чуть подробней все рапишу.

Comment: ` Структура СтруктураТест = new Структура();
            int i = СтруктураТест.Количество();
            СтруктураТест.Вставить("белый", 10);
            
            Assert.Equal(СтруктураТест.Количество(), i + 1);
            Assert.Equal(10,СтруктураТест["белый"]);
            Assert.True(СтруктураТест.ContainsKey("Белый")); ` Этого достаточно ?

Comment: Юнит тесты нужны, чтобы не было регрессии когда делаешь новые фичи или правишь баги. Т.к. проетестировать все руками просто нереально. Достаточно ли этого для тебя, я хз. У многих компаний есть свои требования к коверейджу и его проценту.

Comment: А как проверить именно на Валидность ключей ?

Comment: Проверка данных на валидность, это не ответственность юнитестов. Можешь добавить метод IsValid() и в нем реализовать проверку валидности данных. А после покрыть этот метод тестами.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу менять сами методы и классы. Моя задача протестировать уже имеющийся функционал. Поэтому хотел уточнить по поводу 2) try и catch нету в вызываемом коде. Получается мне надо протестировать встроенные стандартные исключения с помощью цикла foreach и только? Но как ? Представление имеется, но так как плохо знаком с синтаксисом не могу сообразить.

Comment: Проверять такие исключение как IndexOutOfRangeException или KeyNotFoundException и т.д., смысла нет. т.к. их рейз гарантирован спецификцацией языка.

Comment: Можете подсказать какие исключения ещё можно создать в моём случае ,на подобие  ItemNotFoundException ?